# IIS response by 500 error after request by SOAP message (module ISAPI)

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, iis-7

Hello when i try to request my web service deploied on IIS i get the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 21 Dec 2011 12:53:36 GMT
Connection: close
```

I configured Failed Request Tracer for any modules and i hope to get detailed errors with stacktrace but I got only this:

....

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="ASPNET" Guid="{AFF081FE-0247-4275-9C4E-021F3DC1DA35}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>0</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>11</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x2</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-12-21T12:53:36.787Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0200-0080000000FB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="4280" ThreadID="4952"/>
  <Computer>LOBASTOV-A</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ConnID">20313736</Data>
  <Data Name="Context ID">{00000000-0000-0000-0200-0080000000FB}</Data>
  <Data Name="Data1">System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="ru-RU">
  <Opcode>AspNetPipelineLeave</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>Module</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{06A01367-79D3-4594-8EB3-C721603C4679}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="ASPNET" Guid="{AFF081FE-0247-4275-9C4E-021F3DC1DA35}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>0</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>12</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x1</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-12-21T12:53:36.787Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0200-0080000000FB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="4280" ThreadID="4952"/>
  <Computer>LOBASTOV-A</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ConnID">20313736</Data>
  <Data Name="Context ID">{00000000-0000-0000-0200-0080000000FB}</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="ru-RU">
  <Opcode>AspNetMapHandlerEnter</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>Infrastructure</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{06A01367-79D3-4594-8EB3-C721603C4679}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>3</Level>
  <Opcode>16</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-12-21T12:53:36.896Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0200-0080000000FB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="4280" ThreadID="4952"/>
  <Computer>LOBASTOV-A</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-0200-0080000000FB}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">IsapiModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">128</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpStatus">500</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpReason">Internal Server Error</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpSubStatus">0</Data>
  <Data Name="ErrorCode">0</Data>
  <Data Name="ConfigExceptionInfo"></Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="ru-RU">
  <Opcode>MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER</freb:Description>
  <freb:Description Data="ErrorCode">Операция успешно завершена.
 (0x0)</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>1</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-12-21T12:53:36.896Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0200-0080000000FB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="4280" ThreadID="4952"/>
  <Computer>LOBASTOV-A</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-0200-0080000000FB}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">WindowsAuthenticationModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">536870912</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotification">false</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="ru-RU">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_START</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">SEND_RESPONSE</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
```

....

And here my SOAP request:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ns2:updateBill xmlns:ns2="http://client.ishop.mw.ru/">
      <login>test</login>
      <password>test</password>
      <txn>test</txn>
      <status>1</status>
    </ns2:updateBill>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Can anybody help me to understand what is wrang? Or say how to get the detailed errors with stacktrace?

Comment: Error 500 is an internal server error. This could be due to unhandled exceptions occurring on the server while processing your request. Have you checked (or can you check) the OS Event Log to see if there are any errors recorded there?

Comment: Hello Strillo. I checked logs by Event Viewer but I didn't find any errors for my request. There are only 2 warning messages:  
1 - Wile creating existing folder {3eb685db-65f9-4cf6-a03a-e3ef65729f3d} with path "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming" error occured 0x80070005.  <br/>  <br/>
2 - Wile checking existing folder {352481e8-33be-4251-ba85-6007caedcf9d} with path "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files" error occured 0x80070005.

Answer (score 0):

Error 0x80070005 means ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED. The Roaming folder contains some CLR Security Config file. Try and check if the account under which the service is running has administrator permission (that should also solve access to the Tempor‌​ary Internet Files folder).

Comment: It's true... I am open access for users IIS_IUSRS and the warning message doesn't apear else. But it doesn't solve my problem with SOAP request.

Comment: Ok, then it could be something wrong with the SOAP request. Could you post it?

Comment: Ok, I post it in question above.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider this as SOAP level error (as it is not a general IIS 500). Read the SOAP protocol in details, and you will see what may be the cause,

http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-soap12-part0-20070427/

http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-soap12-part2-20070427/

My guess is that the server application cannot process the SOAP requests.

Comment: I don't think so, because this request worked good before I am update my project - I just added new method to my service.